# iterate over a macro list in SAS

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I am trying to use a macro variable for the first time,

I have many tables produced every month and I would like for each table take only two variable, so I have created a macro to avoid redundancies in my code but the problem is that the macro variables are not recognized in the data step

```
    %LET OLDTABLES = 
oc201710.A20171001_active_households
oc201709.A20170901_active_households ;


* List of tables processed (ex with two tables);
%LET NEWTABLES = 
A20171001_HH
A20170901_HH ;


%MACRO VARTEST(x1=&OLDTABLES,x2=&NEWTABLES);



* Loop over the table;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&x1.));
    %LET FLAGP = %sysfunc(scan(&x2., &i));
    * get the 7 first characters from the table name;
    %LET VARFLAG = %sysfunc(substr(&FLAGP,1,7));
    %LET OLDTAB = %scan(&x1., &i);
    %LET NEWTAB = %scan(&x2., &i);

    %PUT &OLDTAB;
    %PUT &NEWTAB;

    * data step: keeping only the key + create new variable from the name of the table;
    rsubmit;
    data &NEWTAB (keep=cust_key &VARFLAG_f_act_n &VARFLAG_Households);
    set &OLDTAB;
    &VARFLAG._f_act_n = f_act_n;
    &VARFLAG._Households = 1;
    run;
    endrsubmit;
%end;
%mend VARTEST;

options mprint mfile;
filename mprint 'external-file';    
%VARTEST(x1=&OLDTABLES.,x2=&NEWTABLES.);
```

Here what I get as an output,:

```
    836
837  * data step: keeping only the key + create new variable from the name of the table
838  options mprint mfile;
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OLDTABLES not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NEWTABLES not resolved.
MPRINT(VARTEST):   * Loop over the table;
839  filename mprint 'external-file';
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X1 resolves to &OLDTABLES.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OLDTABLES not resolved.
840  %VARTEST(x1=&OLDTABLES.,x2=&NEWTABLES.);
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X2 resolves to &NEWTABLES.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NEWTABLES not resolved.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 1
MPRINT(VARTEST):   * get the 7 first characters from the table name;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FLAGP resolves to NEWTABLES
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X1 resolves to &OLDTABLES.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference OLDTABLES not resolved.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 1
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable X2 resolves to &NEWTABLES.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference NEWTABLES not resolved.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable I resolves to 1
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable OLDTAB resolves to OLDTABLES
OLDTABLES
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable NEWTAB resolves to NEWTABLES
NEWTABLES
MPRINT(VARTEST):   rsubmit
```

Comment: include any errors or explain what is happening. You should run this with the `options mprint symbolgen;` on to see the full list of errors.

Comment: thanks for the tips, it's very helpful

Answer (score 2):

First off, it looks like you didn't run the part of your code defining `&oldtables` and `&newtables`.

Second, your `%SYSFUNC(COUNTW(...` is wrong.  `COUNTW` takes lots of things as delimiters, including `.` which means you have more than 2 words there.  Give it the optional second argument:

```
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&x1.,%str( )));
```

(That's how you show 'space' in macro language, by the way).

Third, you have some issues with macro variables not being delimited properly.  `&VARFLAG_f_act_n` needs to be `&VARFLAG._f_act_n`; you do that right later but you don't in the keep statement for either variable.  (You could probably just `keep &varflag:` by the way plus the other variables in that list.)

This works for me.  I obviously can't do all of what you can because of not having the datsets, but this works as expected.

Also, I hope you're aware that your `RSUBMIT` session does not know about the macro variables. They're parsed by the local session before the `RSUBMIT` happens.  But if you have some macro variable that needs to be processed on the server side, you'll have to `%SYSLPUT` or `%SYSRPUT` that variable.

```
 %LET OLDTABLES = oc201710.A20171001_active_households oc201709.A20170901_active_households ;

* List of tables processed (ex with two tables);
%LET NEWTABLES = A20171001_HH A20170901_HH ;
options autosignon=yes;

%let sasloc = "C:\Program Files\sas94\sasfoundation\9.4\sas.exe";  *path to sas.exe;

signon process=a 
        sascmd=&sasloc.;


%MACRO VARTEST(x1=&OLDTABLES,x2=&NEWTABLES);



* Loop over the table;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&x1.,%str( )));
    %LET FLAGP = %sysfunc(scan(&x2., &i));
    * get the 7 first characters from the table name;
    %LET VARFLAG = %sysfunc(substr(&FLAGP,1,7));
    %LET OLDTAB = %scan(&x1., &i);
    %LET NEWTAB = %scan(&x2., &i);

    %PUT &OLDTAB;
    %PUT &NEWTAB;

    * data step: keeping only the key + create new variable from the name of the table;
    rsubmit process=a;
    %put &=newtab. &=oldtab. &=Varflag.;
    endrsubmit;
%end;
%mend VARTEST;

%VARTEST(x1=&OLDTABLES.,x2=&NEWTABLES.);
```

Comment: hey thanks for the code but I run sas via a remote server, I don't have any idea about the location of sas.exe

Comment: @ratonroguille You don't have to, this is just an example code - I added that so I could show what happens with the RSUBMIT.  You of course connect however you want to.  The important part is the adding of the third argument to the word scanner, and making sure you actually run all of the code.